# Passing URL parameter from JSP to Servlet, parameter changes

Tags: jsp, servlets, url-parameters

I am pretty new to JSP/Servlets, I have been working on something and it was working for a while. I have a jsp named 'telGir.jsp' and I pass a URL parameter from this JSP to a servlet named 'telKayit'

An example URL for the JSP page when I am running on localhost:

```
http://localhost:9081/Pol/telGir.jsp?token=3403123412340000
```

This is my jsp's code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>

</head>
<body

<p align="center"><font size="14"><b>TEXT</b></font></p>
<p align="center"><font size="14">MORE TEXT</font></p>
<table align="center" size="800">
<form name="Police" id="Police" action="telKayit?token=${param.token}" method="post">

</table>
<table align="center" size="800">
<tr><td align="center"><input type="submit" value="Tamam" style="height:2.5em; width:7.5em;font-size: 51px "></td></tr>

</table></form>

</body>
</html>
```

When the button is pressed the form takes me to this URL:

```
http://localhost:9081/Pol/telKayit?token=3403123412340000
```

Finally in my servlet I use this line of code to get the token from the above link:

```
String token = request.getParameter("token");
```

This has worked for me so far because the tokens consisted of numbers. Recently I was asked to put encoded texts for tokens, so the new URL for the jsp would be something like:

```
http://localhost:9081/Pol/telGir.jsp?token=6amyutm%2F%2BhZeXxJonjEBqduaQVlXuO3%2FUAffs2MSyBs%3D
```

Here is the problem: When the token parameter is being passed from JSP to Servlet for some reason the '%' causes it to change. When I press the button the below link appears which has a different 'token' value.

```
http://localhost:9081/Pol/telKayit?token=6amyutm/+hZeXxJonjEBqduaQVlXuO3/UAffs2MSyBs=
```

As the parameter changes when I receive it in the servlet I cannot properly decode it and get my result. From what I researched I have realized the '%' sign makes my code interpret the following two characters as ASCII. So: 2F becomes '/' and 2B becomes '+' etc. How can I stop this and let it just pass the 'token' as a regular string variable without changing it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting parameter in the action url you should pass it as hidden input in form, like that:

```
<form name="Police" id="Police" action="telKayit" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="${param.token}"
...
</form>
```